# How to map some data to the data fetched from API before showing it on screen?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I am trying to make an app of my own to try out the different things that I learnt and also get to know new things and one such thing that I came across and is giving me a hard time is the following issue: 
I have an API which gives me certain data about an item. The properties of the item are listed in the API like "sizeofitem" , "nameofitem" or "itemacategory". Now there are multiple items for different items and not all properties are present in each item. What I was trying to achieve is to somehow map these properties in the following manner: 
If let's say "sizeofitem", should become "Size of Item", "nameofitem" should become "Name of Item". Now these properties are different of all the items so for example, sizeofitem might be in one item detail list but might not be in another, but I have all the properties that are can be there. Can someone help me how to do this?

Till now I have the following:

```
const [itemDtl , setItemDtl] = useState([]);

const getItemInfo = async (id) => {
        try{
            const response = await api.get(`myAPI/${id}`);
            setItemDtl(response.data.obj.itemutils);

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
let arr = [];
for(let i in itemDtl){

   arr.push(itemDtl[i].util_type);
}
console.log(arr);

useEffect(() => {
    getItemInfo(id);
})
```

arr array has whatever the properties where listed for the item in the API i.e. [sizeofitem, nameofitem , etc].

I want an array to have [Size of Item, Name of Item , etc].

Basically just, to sum up, I want to rename the list of properties that can be there for when whatever property comes up is then stored in an array with the mapped string I have given, so for example if an item has 'sizeofitem : 50', I want it to be stored as  "Size of item"  so that I can show that on the screen. And there are like a total of 5 properties that can exist for an item so I can code it somewhere maybe like `sizeofitem : 'Size Of Item'` so that when sizeofitem property is top be shown on the screen I can use this and show Size of Item on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const [itemDtl , setItemDtl] = useState([]);

const getItemInfo = async (id) => {
        try{
            const response = await api.get(`myAPI/${id}`);
            let arr = [];
            for(let i in itemDtl){
              arr.push(itemDtl[i].util_type);
            }
            setItemDtl(arr);

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }


useEffect(() => {
    getItemInfo(id);
})
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. But wouldn't this just give me the same thing only? I have updated my question at the end a bit in case I wasn't clear earlier. Sorry. New to stackoverflow.